# Analysing the behaviour of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, parametric

I need to analyse the behaviour of the following function in parametric form as t tends to positive infinity:
$$ t = m(\sinh2x - 2x)$$
$$ a = m(\cosh2x - 1)$$

The question asks to show that for large t we have that a increases linearly with time.

First thing I tried to do is to analyse what should be happening to x so that t is large. And since $\sinh x$ can be expressed in terms of exponentials:
$$ t = m\cdot \left(\dfrac{e^{2x}- e^{-2x}}{2} - 2x\right)$$

We can see that $e^{2x}$ will dominate all the terms and so $x$ will need to tend to positive infinity so that we obtain large value for $t$. As $x$ tends to positive infinity:
$$ a = m\cdot\left(\dfrac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2} - 1\right)$$

So as $x$ becomes larger, a will tend to $\frac{e^{2x}}{2}$ which is not linear.

There must be something that I did wrong or something I just don't see in the problem. I would also appreciate if someone could give me advice on how to sketch this function in parametric form.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a desmos.com graph with a slider for $m$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zzhecaltkz You can zoom in and out with the mouse wheel. Notice what graph it resembles when you zoom out.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thank you for your reply! It looks like y = |x|, however, I am not sure what is the reason for it

Comment: Try taking $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{t}{a}$. This will tell you something about the relationship of $a$ to $t$ for large $x$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Sorry for bothering you again but I got that t/a will tend to 1. Is it right by any chance?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Can I then assume that if t/a tends to 1, so will a/t which is the gradient and so if it tends to 1, then the whole function will be linear in the form y = x as t increases?

Comment: This only shows that it approaches a linear function with slope equal to $1$. It does not tell you what the $y$-intercept of the linear function will be. One cannot assume that it will be $0$.

Comment: Note, however, that if you were only asked to show that for large $t$, $a$ increases linearly with respect to time. I assume $t$ represents time? To do that you have only to show that $\Delta a/\Delta t\to c$ for some constant $c$. And you now see that this is true for $c=1$.

Comment: Correction, $c=1$ for positive $m$.